# Timer for drivers

Tags: animation, drivers

Is it possible to make a driver delay?
If a driver takes effect, I would like to keep it that way for a few seconds, even if it normally would not effect the mesh anymore.

Note:
I use a condition to define the driver value.

Comment: Though there is some possibility of higher logic with pyDrivers I would do this with app.handlers.

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail @Jerryno?

Comment: For the delay to work the driver must know how long ago it was trigerred. This information has to be somewhere stored and also modified. Simple driver cannot do this. But PyDriver can. But it is also limited. With writing your own scene handler you can do anything you want. If you want to learn more search for `PyDriver` or `bpy.app.handlers`.